# How do I insert a tab character in a Google Docs document on iOS?

Tags: ios, text-editor, google-apps, google-docs

I'm trying to insert a tab character in a Google "doc", from Google Drive on my iPhone.

I have a list

1. Item
2. Thing

and I need to insert an `a.` between 1 and 2 - usually accomplished by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which is not present on the onscreen keyboard.

How do I accomplish this task (on iOS)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Google Drive app, within a Google document, there are two indentation keys in the top status bar. You'll need to scroll right to get to them. The right one works just like Tab, and the other is for Shift+Tab.

[image: The two toolbar buttons]

Comment: This actually changes the indent for the whole paragraph. It’s not a tab key.

Answer (score 4):

I almost threw my phone out the window / abandoned the Docs ecosystem - thinking that you couldn't do this…

After some searching, and poking around a little bit to no avail, voila!

[image: use Siri, yo]

We're gonna "use Siri", here... so enable dictation, in iOS settings, if not already "ON".

Hit the mic, and say...

*Tab Key*

Drop the mic.

Hard tabs, *all day long*. Thank God!

Comment: If this worked, it doesn’t anymore. Siri says she doesn’t understand. I tried a few variations.

Comment: @screenglow You need to do this via the system's [built-in dictation feature](https://i.imgur.com/DSalgde.png) , **NOT** Siri.  Just confirmed it still works (on iOS 13.5)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to do one, I'd try to copy one from somewhere else in the document.

As far as I can tell there is no way to input a tab character in iOS without an external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Click on [image] symbol on top-right corner when in editing mode. Then Text/Paragraph editing option, as shown below, will open at the bottom. Click on Paragraph tab to get options for indent

[image]